# Wien's Displacement Law and reradiation of LWIR by $\rm CO_2$

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, thermal-radiation, atmospheric-science

Consider Wien's Displacement Law (if I understand correctly): λ = b / T
Where,
λ = Peak Wavelength
b = 0.028977 mK (Wien's constant)
T = Temperature

According to this law $\rm CO_2$ molecules can only absorb and reradiate the Long Wave I.R. frequency (radiated from Earth) in their 15 micrometre (μm) spectrum at a temperature of -80 degrees Celcius. The link with temperature seems crucial to me since the only part of our athmosphere cold enough for this to happen is the Mesosphere at about 50-80 km from Earth. Troposphere and Stratosphere are not cold enough (coldest temperature is about -55 degrees Celsius). In these parts of our atmosphere it is just not cold enough for $\rm CO_2$ to reradiate I.R. wavelengths back to Earth. Then why is $\rm CO_2$ considered a greenhouse gas in our Tropo- or Stratosphere? Am I missing out on something here?

In the Mesosphere, however, temperature can drop to over -100 degrees Celsius. In this part of the atmosphere $\rm CO_2$ can reradiate LWIR back to Earth. But the problem is that the air is so thin, there are hardly any molecules of $\rm CO_2$.

What am I missing here in my reasoning?

Comment: Wien's displacement law is about intensity of radiation of blackbody or solid body that is close to blackbody. How do you mean to apply it to CO2 gas in atmosphere? It doesn't imply "CO2 molecules can only absorb and reradiate the Long Wave I.R. frequency (radiated from Earth) in their 15 micrometre (μm) spectrum at a temperature of -80 degrees Celcius."

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.

Answer (score 2):

Wein's displacement law has to do with how the *peak* in a blackbody spectrum shifts with temperature.  It does not have anything to do with whether a particular temperature is required for a substance to absorb or radiate at that wavelength.

Carbon dioxide will both absorb and radiate at 15 $\mu$m in the both troposphere and stratosphere.  If radiation at the correct wavelength exists, then CO2 molecules will absorb it.  Usually, they get knocked around and lose the excess energy through collisions, thereby acting to increase the temperature of the atmosphere.  But they can also be knocked into a higher energy level through collisions and then lose the energy through radiation in a random direction.

A good paper on this is [Infrared Radiation and Planetary Temperature](https://geosci.uchicago.edu/%7Ertp1/papers/PhysTodayRT2011.pdf).